# Is it possible to do conditional destructuring or have a fallback?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that has lots of deeply nested properties. I want to be able to access properties on "MY_KEY" (below), but if that doesn't exist then get "MY_OTHER_KEY". How can I accomplish that?

```
const {
  X: {
    Y: {
      MY_KEY: {
        Values: segments = []
      } = {}
    } = {}
  } = {}
} = segment;
```

Comment: Can you include the code at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you mean by 'other key'? It's easy enough to check if a key is `undefined`, but how do you select the alternative?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite `MY_KEY` with value of `MY_OTHER_KEY` within target if `MY_KEY` is `undefined` within source?

Comment: Yes. And ideally succinctly rather than duplicating the destructuring.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's that I'm unfamiliar with something here or if the code is really reductive, but this doesn't seem valid to begin with?

Comment: If what exactly doesn't exist, you want to get the value `"MY_OTHER_KEY"` exactly where? Or do you mean you want to get the property `.MY_OTHER_KEY` - of what object exactly, and what do you want to do with it then?

Comment: It would help if you could provide working (but possibly tedious and extensive) code without destructuring syntax that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve this using a temporal variable inside your destructuring assignment, something like this:

```js
function destructure(segments) {
  const {
    X: {
      Y: {
        MY_OTHER_KEY: _fallback_value = {},
        MY_KEY: {
          Values: segment = []
        } = _fallback_value,
      } = {},
    } = {},
  } = segments;

  return segment;
}

console.log(destructure({})); // []
console.log(destructure({X:{}})); // []
console.log(destructure({X:{Y:{MY_KEY:{Values:"A"}}}})); // A
console.log(destructure({X:{Y:{MY_OTHER_KEY:{Values:"B"}}}})); // B
console.log(destructure({X:{Y:{MY_OTHER_KEY:{Values:"C"}, MY_KEY:{Values:"D"}}}})); // D
```

First of all, this kind of destructuring will attempt to extract the second key all the time, which might have some unintended implications, like a property getter for `MY_OTHER_KEY` will always run.

However I fail to see the beauty in it. Hiding some control flow inside destructuring is just confusing. I would rather suggest extracting the parent object and use regular property access on it:

```js
function destructure(segments) {
  const {
    X: {
      Y: nested = {},
    } = {},
  } = segments;
  const selected = nested.MY_KEY || nested.MY_OTHER_KEY || {};
  const {
    Values: segment = []
  } = selected;
  return segment;
}

console.log(destructure({})); // []
console.log(destructure({X:{}})); // []
console.log(destructure({X:{Y:{MY_KEY:{Values:"A"}}}})); // A
console.log(destructure({X:{Y:{MY_OTHER_KEY:{Values:"B"}}}})); // B
console.log(destructure({X:{Y:{MY_OTHER_KEY:{Values:"C"}, MY_KEY:{Values:"D"}}}})); // D
```

Comment: Notice you can also place the `{
    Values: segment = []
  }` destructuring target right in place of the `extracted` variable (in the `MY_KEY: extracted = _second_value,` line). Saves one line and one unnecessary identifier, but probably increases complexity (which was the point of the first snippet though, wasn't it?).

Comment: @Bergi nice, I will do that but only strictly for demonstration purposes

Comment: Thats kinda beautiful in an ugly way :}

Answer (score 1):

Check if the target is defined

```
let {/* do destructuring stuff */}

if (MY_KEY === undefined) {
  // define `MY_OTHER_KEY` variable here
}
```

If you are trying to assign target to a different property if the previous target definition is `undefined` you can assign the variable at subsequent target definition

```js
const segment = {Y:123};
let or = "Y";
let X;
({X, X = X || segment[or]} = segment);

console.log(X);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply write `let {X = segment.Y} = segment`? If you absolutely want to use `||`, you shouldn't do it inside a destructuring expression to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Bergi Did not consider that option. To the degree that am currently able to comprehend what expected result is it appears that OP might want to reassign `X` within target if the previously defined `X` is `undefined`. There would not be confusion for OP, if that is what they are trying to achieve. The present Question is not clear as to what expected result of `MY_KEY` is, though an answer does exist whatever OP is expecting `MY_KEY` and `MY_OTHER_KEY` to be. It is up to OP to decide what the variables should be. This is a case of the possibility is defined, though the expected result is not.

Answer (score 1):

While object destructuring is cool and new, it is not the best in all cases. May do:

```
try {   
  var segments = segment.X.Y.MY_KEY.Values;
} catch(e){
 //whatever
}
```

Comment: I agree. I was going to answer similarly with destructoring in a try/catch block. Otherwise you could do a ternary check for MY_KEY. There's nothing wrong with destructoring but in this example it seems like alternatives may be much more appropriate.