# How to conditionally destructure on object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following destructuring:

```js
const {
    user: {
        username,
        image,
        uid
    } = {},
    gallery: {
        image: picture,
    } = {},
} = data
```

The problem is `gallery` is sometimes `null` (not the `picture` within `gallery`), even though what I need is the `picture` within `gallery` when it exists. In other words, `gallery: null`, not `gallery.image: null`.

Therefore, I get:

> null is not an object

error message for `gallery.image`.

How do I conditionally destructure so that `gallery.image` is used when it exists, but `gallery` isn't destructured when null?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do conditional destructuring or have a fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816095/is-it-possible-to-do-conditional-destructuring-or-have-a-fallback)

Comment: i've actually seen that post and I have the empty object `{}` as the fallback value as well for 'gallery', but I'm still getting the `null is not an object` error

Comment: I think I'd be more tempted to ask the question, is this maybe a bit TOO destructured. That's going to be a bit difficult to grok later on.

Comment: [Default values are applied only if the destructured value is `undefined`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) Since it looks like it's `null` in your case, default value are useless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fallbacks only work when the value is `undefined` but not `null`

- This will work:

```js
const data = {
  user: {
    username: 'Alice',
    image: 'alice.png',
    uid: 1
  },
  gallery: undefined
};

const {
    user: {
        username,
        image,
        uid
    } = {},
    gallery: {
        image: picture,
    } = {},
} = data;

console.log(username, image, uid, picture);
```

- But this won't:

```js
const data = {
  user: {
    username: 'Alice',
    image: 'alice.png',
    uid: 1
  },
  gallery: null
};

const {
    user: {
        username,
        image,
        uid
    } = {},
    gallery: {
        image: picture,
    } = {},
} = data;

console.log(username, image, uid, picture);
```

---

#### So, you can manually create a fallback from `null` to `{}` before you destructing it like this:

```js
const data = {
  user: {
    username: 'Alice',
    image: 'alice.png',
    uid: 1
  },
  gallery: null
};

const {
    user: {
        username,
        image,
        uid
    } = {},
    gallery: {
      image: picture,
    }
} = {...data, gallery: data.gallery || {}};

console.log(username, image, uid, picture);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you explain this part `gallery: data.gallery`?

Comment: It's `gallery: data.gallery || {}`. The property `gallery` gets value from `data.gallery` by default. `data.gallery || {}` means if `data.gallery` is a truthy value, just use the value; if it's a falsy value *(`null`, `undefined`, `0`, etc.)* , use `{}` instead.

Comment: Then finally, properties from `data` and processed `gallery` property combine into one object and ready for destruction.

Comment: OK now I understand. Thank you